# getting values of inner objects with php

Tags: php, object, nested

I think this is a basic question, but I just can't get it right and its really crazy...
i tried turning it into an array and many other things, but I just don't get it right.
How can I access the value in the Country index with PHP? I tried so many ways and just can't get directly to it.
this is the object:`

```
 [type] => Contact
[fields] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FirstName] => my
        [LastName] => name
        [0] => SObject Object
            (
                [type] => Account
                [fields] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Country] => Netherlands
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

I tried accessing the [0] as an array (object returns error) but still nothing.
thanks, and sorry if its a silly question - i have to say here was quite a research effort but for no avail...

Answer (score 0):

Cast your object to array with

```
$array = (array)$object;
$inner_obj = $array[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I was never aware of this syntax:$contact->fields->{0}... is it an array inside the object? or just a property with a number instead of name. thanks for the help :)